# dynamo Db contains

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I am very new to dynamodb, i got stuck up with a situation here. I am working on a code which is already available here. My requirement is I want to change my query to add a filter.

My current code is

```
reqObj.TableName = config.storeTableName;
   reqObj.FilterExpression = "isActive = :isActive AND isDeleted = :isDeleted AND #state = :stateName",
   reqObj.ExpressionAttributeNames = {"#state": "state"};
   reqObj.ExpressionAttributeValues= {":isActive": true, ":isDeleted": false , ":city": cityName , ":stateName" : region_code},
```

I want to check whether a specific value is there in city, i browsed and found out CONTAINS parameter will be suitable. But don't know where to add

Suppose i want to check whether the city contains a value "LOS ANGELES", where the code should be placed in the above code.

will It Be like this

```
reqObj.TableName = config.storeTableName;
       reqObj.FilterExpression = "isActive = :isActive AND isDeleted = :isDeleted AND CONTAINS(city = :city) AND  #state = :stateName",
       reqObj.ExpressionAttributeNames = {"#state": "state"};
       reqObj.ExpressionAttributeValues= {":isActive": true, ":isDeleted": false , ":city": cityName , ":stateName" : region_code},
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I got it myself, I have to change my query like this

```
reqObj.FilterExpression = "isActive = :isActive AND isDeleted = :isDeleted AND CONTAINS(city, :city) AND  #state = :stateName",
```

contains, is a function which will have the list of values , with the key value along with it

Thanks